# how to add dataset in Drupal using API

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, dataset, dkan

I am very new to DRUPAl and DKAN. I have an existing application built using DRUPAL and DKAN. I want to expose a functionality from this Drupal based application such that it exposes an API using which I can add dataset. This new API will be consumed by another application.

I have tried googling but could not find anything very specific.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is an example of adding a dataset through the API.

```
// Set up request URL.
$request_url = 'http://example.com/api/dataset/node';

// Set up dataset data.
// A great explanation on how to target each node field can be found on the 'Identifying field names' article linked on the 'Documentation' section.
$dataset_data = array(
    'type' => 'dataset',
    'title' => 'Example dataset',
    'status' => 1,
    'body[und][0][value]' => 'The description',
    'field_resources[und][0][target_id]' => 'Madison Polling Places (5)', // Resource title plus node id
    'field_author[und][0][value]' => 'Bob Lafollette'
);
$dataset_data = http_build_query($dataset_data);

// Set up request.
$curl = curl_init($request_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json', 'X-CSRF-Token: ' . $csrf_token));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1); // Do a regular HTTP POST.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dataset_data); // Set POST data.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "$cookie_session");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, TRUE);

// Execute request and get response.
$response = curl_exec($curl);
```

for more details you can check the official documentation at http://docs.getdkan.com/en/latest/apis/rest-api.html